# The inverse of TcpClient.GetStream - Getting The TcpClient associated with a given NetworkStream

Tags: c#, stream, tcpclient

Is there any way to accomplish the inverse of `TcpClient.GetStream()`, meaning - getting the `TcpClient` that is associated with a given `NetworkStream`?

If not, how else can I get the ***amount***  of available data (not to be confused with the availability of data in general , which is retrievable by `NetworkStream.DataAvailable`) on the `NetworkStream` ?

Comment: Why don't you simply store the TcpClient yourself?

Comment: Network streams are endless, so the Length() property is meaningless and not implemented.  Simply read the stream and it will tell you how much it returned (there could be more left waiting to be read, depends on the size of your buffer).  Base your logic off the actual data received.  Only YOU can decide when "all" (or enough) of the data has arrived for you to take action.  It's up to you to design a COMMUNICATION PROTOCOL that will allow you to determine when a "complete message" has been received, based solely on the data you've received so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such function, at least none that I know of. Stream.Length is meaningless on a network stream, because you never know the remaining amount of data. That said, you're probably having a conceptual error there: The network stream just delivers data, there's no way to know how much data is left in the stream, because the other end can continuously send data on it, theoretically forever. If you want to know the size of i.e. a file you're downloading, you'll have to parse the *contents* of the network stream, assuming the protocol in use does send such an information.

Comment: OK. I don't sure though about having a conceptual error, as the `NetworkStream` is an "interface" to the `TcpClient` in some sense, and the `TcpClient` itself *DOES* have such a property. as @user2674389 suggested , I'll just use it (the problem before was that I only passed the `NetworkStream` instead of the `TcpClient` , or both.

Comment: Also TcpClient.Available just returns the number of bytes _currently_ available in the buffer. It doesn't give any information about the amount of data that will be available in total.